# Connect 2 different buttons to the same outlet (Swift)

Tags: swift

I want to connect a second button to a label `@IBOutlet var ourScore: UILabel!` . 
The first button is connected as

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    ourScore.text = "\(++score)"
}
```

How is it possible that I can add another button to the label, so when you click on the second button it works together. The first one counts it up and the second one needs to reset it, back to 0.

Comment: I have to vote this as unclear what you're asking.  And if the question were any more clear, it'd be a duplicate of *something*.  Are you trying to hook up multiple items with outlets?  Are you trying to hook up multiple items to the *same* outlet?  Are you trying to hook up multiple items to **actions**?

Answer (score 1):

Your button isn't linked to your label outlet, the code of your IBAction makes reference to it. You posted this method:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) 
{
    ourScore.text = "\(++score)"
}
```

so create a new method:

```
@IBAction func resetButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) 
{
    score = 0;
    ourScore.text = "\(score)"
}
```

Link that second IBAction method to your second button. Done.

Answer (score 0):

You create the button in the same exact way you created the first one but instead of ++ it'd be -- (or whatever you want it to be).

The label is available to anything inside of your class so you can manipulate it and read from it anywhere.